# Python re.split on "," or " "

Tags: python, regex

Trying to get re.split to work correctly.
Input = "a1 a2 a3, a4,a5"

```
expecting output = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5']
s = re.split(',|\s', "a1 a2 a3, a4,a5")
getting output = ['a1','a2','a3',' ','a4','a5']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to allow one or more split characters:

```
>>> re.split('[,\s]+', "a1 a2 a3, a4,a5")
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```